# How to move files in unix in a way that we save all of the atributes

Tags: unix

I had this question in my exam today, I'can't seem to find an answer for it : 
how to move all found fit files placed in root and move them in fit directory in a way that we save all atributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question sounds a little vague: the first one and immediate answer is that you use the `cp(1)` command with `--preserve=all`. From the manpage:

> --preserve[=ATTR_LIST] preserve the specified attributes (default: mode,ownership,timestamps), if possible additional attributes:
>   context, links, xattr, all

It looks like you're taking an operating systems class though, so I assume that the exam was not testing your ability to know all the possible options to `cp(1)`. The question is (probably) about how to do it in code (or rather, how `cp(1)` does it).

Programmatically, you could do it like this:

- Open the source directory with `opendir(3)`.
- Iteratively fetch each entry in the directory with `readdir(3)`. Each call to `readdir(3)` will return a `struct dirent`, which, among other things, contains the inode of that entry, the filename, and the type of file (you may want to recursively repeat the process if the file type is a directory)
- For each regular file entry, `open(2)` the file with `O_RDONLY`. Also `open(2)` the same filename in the target directory with `O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC` (write only mode, truncate the file if it already exists, create it if it doesn't).
- Copy the contents as usual with `read(2)` and `write(2)`.
- Call `fstat(2)` on the source file to get all the attributes.
- Call `fchmod(2)` on the target file to set the permissions to be the same as those in the `st_mode` field of the stat structure of the source file.
- Call `fchown(2)` on the target file to set the owner and group to be the same as the `st_uid` and `st_gid` fields of the stat structure of the source file.
- Call `futimens(2)` on the target file to set the access and modification times to be the same as the `st_atime` and `st_mtime` fields of the stat structure of the source file.
- Close the file and process the next file.
- When done, close the directory with `closedir(3)`.

These are all the attributes that you can preserve in a copy. Note that there are still some differences between the two files:

- The ctime (time of last status change, i.e., when the inode was last changed) can't be copied.
- The ID of the device containing the file may be different (depending on where you are copying it to).
- The inode number is obviously different.
- The number of hard links may not be the same.
- The file size may differ if the source file had holes in it. Holes in a file are not necessarily backed by disk storage, but if you naively copy byte by byte from the source to target, the destination file will not have holes and will need more disk space.